# where to get csv sample data?

Tags: validation, sample-data

As part of my development I need to process some .csv files.

For what it matters I am writing a super fast CSV parser in java

I would like to ask if somebody can name some websites where I can find some good csv files so I can test my app.

Please don't tag this question is inappropriate I think developers would benefit from a list 
of good sites where to find sample data

Comment: You can consider all your test cases and generate csv file to have full test cases coverage.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=filetype:csv
I recommend you write one yourself, add empty lines, quoted values which contains commas and newline, add chinese characters, add comments #, also try large files and empty files.

Answer (score 30):

The [baseball archive](http://www.seanlahman.com/baseball-archive/statistics/) can be downloaded in CSV format.  The batting statistics file contains a little over 90,000 rows of data which should be helpful in performance testing your app.

Comment: The file is approximately 8.1 MB in size, to give a sense of scale.

Comment: And to give even more information: The concatenated CSVs are 32MB.

Answer (score 8):

You can download the Sample CSV Data Files from [**this site**](http://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data).

Examples:

[Sample Insurance Data](http://spatialkeydocs.s3.amazonaws.com/FL_insurance_sample.csv.zip)

[Real Estate Data](http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv)

[Sales Transactions Data](http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/SalesJan2009.csv)

Answer (score 6):

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227303/how-to-find-thousands-of-company-names) on [sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sample-data).

I've used http://www.fakenamegenerator.com for these purposes in the past.

Comment: How do I download these fake informations as a CSV file?

Comment: @renatov- see http://www.fakenamegenerator.com/order.php

Answer (score 3):

Another good source is baseball reference. Pick whatever baseball player or manager you can think of.

http://www.baseball-reference.com/managers/coxbo01.shtml

Answer (score 1):

This is a site that is in beta that can give you data in JSON, XML or CSV. All lists are customizable. This is a sample call to return data as CSV: http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=dowjonescompanies&format=csv
Documentation on lists, formats and options under documentation: http://mysafeinfo.com/content/documentation - 
Over 80 data sets available - see a full list under Datasets on the main menu

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for some large CSV files with real-world data, try http://www.baseball-databank.org.

Answer (score 0):

Severals very nice testing csv files : http://support.spatialkey.com/spatialkey-sample-csv-data/

Sample insurance portfolio,
Real estate transactions, 
Sales transactions,
Company Funding Records,
Crime Records

Thank you for the question !