# Interactive Dialog Box in PowerBI

Tags: javascript, python, r, powerbi, m

Is there a way to create an interactive Dialog box in PowerBI?

I have R script embedded into the query editor, and I would like to have an interactive aspect to where I can use:

```
    file<-winDialogString("File input?","")
```

This input would be used as the file location for a read csv and everytime someone opens and executes the Master copy of the PowerBI file, they can input a new file location.

I am also open to html, javascript, python... anything that could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you mentioned in Power BI is to make use of [`parameters`](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/) and parameterize your queries to get the csv file.

Say we have a csv file named [`SalesJan2009.csv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24453288/2684954). When you import it to Power BI you should have something like:

[image: text/csv]

[image: data]

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents("\\Mac\Home\Downloads\SalesJan2009.csv"),[Delimiter=",", Columns=12, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Source, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Transaction_date", type datetime}, {"Product", type text}, {"Price", Int64.Type}, {"Payment_Type", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"City", type text}, {"State", type text}, {"Country", type text}, {"Account_Created", type datetime}, {"Last_Login", type datetime}, {"Latitude", type number}, {"Longitude", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

If we want users to input the file location (i.e. `\\Mac\Home\Downloads\`), we can set up a parameter in Power BI:

[image: new parameter]

[image: file location]

Then we can update the query to use the parameter: (Query -> Advanced Editor)

```
let
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(#"FileLocation" & "SalesJan2009.csv"), ...
    ...
```

If users want to change the parameter (file location) later on, they can edit the parameter and apply changes to refresh the data.

[image: edit parameters]

[image: enter parameters]

[image: apply changes]

P.S. You can even further [export the Power BI file as a template](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/deep-dive-into-query-parameters-and-power-bi-templates/) to allow users to instantiate it as a new Power BI Desktop report (PBIX file).