# Power BI - Reloading data on a page dynamically

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I would like a way to change report data dynamically on a Power BI page.

Is it possible to insert an input component to load one Excel file in a page generated by Power BI, so all visual components automatically show it? If not, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: Where will your Excel files be located? Do you want to achieve so in Power BI Desktop or web?

Comment: @FoxanNg The files will be located in the user's local disk, as the input file component should upload it directly from it.
The main goal is to publish the report. I can use both BI Desktop or BI Service.

Comment: The best you can do is to get file location as `Parameter` from users in Power BI Desktop. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46088266/2684954) help?

Comment: @FoxanNg Thanks, but as the upload should happen on a web page (published report), I think this approach won't solve the problem.

Comment: I'm aware of this so I'm afraid that's the best you can do. What you're looking for is dynamic data source, where Power BI doesn't support (yet?). See, by the time you published the .pbix file to Power BI Service (Web), the data set is fixed and you can't change it.

Comment: You can take a look at [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/) which has [integration with Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-tile-in-powerapps/). This may be the end solution you're looking for.

Comment: Or maybe Power Update?